# finding records within date range irrespective of year

Tags: sql

I want to find records within a date range say between 15th August and 15th December, irrespective of the year.
So basically I want all records from month 8 to 12 and none from 1st to 14th day of 8th month and and 16th to 31st day of 12th month.

I already can do this in two ways

1. by using multiple conditions using "and/or" or cases in where clause.
2. by using day no. of the year (ofcourse handling leap years).

I just want to know if there is any other or better way like one line function of formula something

I tried to keep the question explanation as simple as possbile for me. Still if you need it I'll post the explanation using tabular data too. (I'll have to create it though.)

Thanks in advance to all the people who took their time to read and consider the question.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Date/time handling differs between those two products.

Comment: @jarlh : either of them will do. I have already handled the situation. so this is just for knowledge sake

Comment: Without more information than given, I'd probably chose the AND/OR query.

Comment: @Codeek none of them uses the same functions. Date queries though are *infinitely easier and faster* when you use a Calendar table. Instead of trying to parse dates without benefit of indexing, join with a Calendar table that contains dates and separate indexed fields per year, month, day, fortnite,weeknumber etc and filter by the columns you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't see how that helps.

Comment: @Strawberry `dataTable d inner join Calendar on d.Date=Calendar.Date where month between 8 and 12`. With the calendar table fully indexed, that's a simple seek. Without it, the entire data table would have to be scanned to extract the month. Adding custom reporting periods to the Calendar table is trivial too, just add a column to hold the period value. Eg, Semester, Quarter. In this case it looks like a 4-month reporting period

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK - I see; that seems sensible although I'd be interested to see how well it would work in practice.

Comment: @Strawberry that's standard practice for reporting tables and data warehouses. That's what the Date dimension is, a Calendar table. For 1M records it will work 1M times faster *at least*. That's because parsing the date column will prevent the database from using any index on that column. The server will have to scan the entire table to calculate the month/period. With a Calendar table it only has to *seek* the period column and join the data and Calendar tables.

Comment: @Strawberry That of course assuming it's even possible to calculate the period from just a date. Financial/reporting periods are based on laws or business decisions. They aren't based on any formula, but remain the same from one year to another. Should something change only *future* dates are affected. With a calendar table, storing or updating periods is easy and only has to be done once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : That is how you would retrieve data in a much faster way. But how does it work in day filter scenario. I still would need a condition for that. right?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: @Codeek you specified a reporting period, not just days. You can add a filter with the reporting periods as defined by your business in another field in the Calendar table. If the period was 3 months long, you could call it `Quarter` and store `Q1`,`Q2` etc in the reporting field, or just `1,2,3,4`. You'll have to pick a name that has meaning for your business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not particularly efficient, but I would expect to see something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%m-%d') BETWEEN '08-15' AND '12-14' 
 ORDER 
    BY dt;
```

Comment: In SQL Server you could use   where FORMAT(MyDate,'MM-dd') between '08-15' and '12-15'

Answer (score 0):

Would you be looking for something like this? The idea is to transmute every date into the same year, in this case, year 1.  To do that, subtract the appropriate number of years.

```
create table MyTable ( MyDate date )

insert into MyTable ( MyDate ) values
( '1889-08-14' ), ( '1891-08-15' ), ( '1899-12-30' ),
( '2018-04-04' ), ( '2018-08-14' ), ( '2018-08-15' ),
( '2018-09-10' ), ( '2018-09-20' ), ( '2018-12-15' ),
( '2018-12-16' ), ( '2019-08-11' ), ( '2019-08-21' ),
( '2019-09-22' ), ( '2019-12-03' ), ( '2019-12-31' ),
( '2020-01-01' ), ( '2030-08-14' ), ( '2040-08-15' ),
( '2050-12-15' ), ( '2060-12-16' ), ( '2222-09-23' )

select * From MyTable 
where DateAdd ( year, 1-Year(MyDate), MyDate ) between '0001-08-15' and '0001-12-15'
```

Result is:

```
MyDate
----------
1891-08-15
2018-08-15
2018-09-10
2018-09-20
2018-12-15
2019-08-21
2019-09-22
2019-12-03
2040-08-15
2050-12-15
2222-09-23
```

If you feel uncomfortable with referencing year 1, you could make it any year.

```
where DateAdd(year, 2000-Year(MyDate), MyDate)between'2000-08-15'and'2000-12-15'
```

In MYSQL this would look something like:

```
where DATE_ADD(MyDate, INTERVAL 1-year(MyDate) YEAR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Sql DATEDIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (d,'2018-08-15','2018-12-16')
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question is how to find *records* in a certain period irrespective of year. `DATEDIFF` returns the number of days between two specific dates